# Check if swap space exist in bash

Tags: bash, swapfile

I want to check whether Swap space exist on a centos box in my bash script.Thus in cash there are no swap space on the server , then i can create swap.

I tried this approach

```
if [[ -n $(swapon -s) ]]; then
    :
else
   mkswap /dev/vda2 &> /dev/null
   swapon /dev/vda2
fi
```

Obviously it won't work since even when there is no swap `swapon -s` will return a string
`Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority`

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/727621/script-to-test-for-swap-then-exit-gracefully

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23072/how-can-i-check-if-swap-is-active-from-the-command-line/537054

Answer (score 10):

This works nicely for me:

```
if free | awk '/^Swap:/ {exit !$2}'; then
    echo "Have swap"
else
    echo "No swap"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a means to do this just using 'swapon' since it:
- always returns at least one line
- always returns an error code of '0'

You could 'count lines' and if less then 2 then take the 'else' branch, i.e.

`if [[ $(swapon -s | wc -l) -gt 1 ]] ;  then echo "OK" ; else echo "Bad" ; fi`

OK

`if [[ $(swapon -s | wc -l) -gt 2 ]] ;  then echo "OK" ; else echo "Bad" ; fi`

Bad

Or simply check for 'devices' in the swapon output, i.e.:

```
if [[ $(swapon -s | grep -ci "/dev" ) -gt 0 ]] ;  then echo "OK" ; else echo "Bad" ; fi
```